get Unexpected token '<' when loading JS file in vue.js + laravel
I try learning laravel 10 with vue inertia by rebuilding my old project I wrote using vue and node.
I use a library to record audio, the code is like this:
recorder = new WebAudioRecorder(input, {
        encoding: encodingType,
        numChannels: 2,
        onEncoderLoading: async function (recorder, encoding) {},
        onEncoderLoaded: async function (recorder, encoding) {},
});

the new WebAudioRecorder will loads from WebAudioRecorder.min.js. in WebAudioRecorder.min.js it creates a new Worker from file WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js.
The code working fine in my old project but when I user laravel I notice that whenever I load the js file, I keep getting redirect back to current file, and I get error:1:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at 1:1:1).
I look into the network and see that after loading WebAudioRecorder.min.js file it will always redirect back to the current file. Because of that the onComplete event never get trigger and return the blob as expected.
Console image 1
Console image 2

After some more research, I found the problem and was able to fix it.
There are two problems, actually:
When the WebAudioRecorder.min.js tries to create new Worker from WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js, it did not load the file correctly, as you can see in this network screenshot; that is why I get redirected back to the current page when it cannot find WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js.

The correct URL content port number http://localhost:5173/; but when specify only the filename at new Worker('WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js') I get:
http://localhost/public/sound/WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js

I then try to get the correct the URL by doing this:
    const url = import.meta.url;
    const parts = url.split('/');
    if (parts.length == 5) {
        parts.pop();
        parts.pop();
    }
    else parts.pop();

Here, I do get the correct URL. However, this led to another problem: The web worker cannot load from another local JavaScript file for security reason, so I get this error:

We need a url for WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js. I found a workaround in this (Chrome can't load web worker):

Step 1: We just need to copy all the code from WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js into a function in WebAudioRecorder.min.js, although it defeats the purpose of writing the code into another JavaScript file.

Step 2: Add the condition (window!=self) to trigger the function—I’m not sure how it works, but it worked for me.

Step 3: We can load the function into our new worker by converting it to a blob and then creating the URL for it.
function worker_function() {
    // all WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js code here
}

if(window!=self)
    worker_function();
    new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+worker_function.toString()+")()"], {type: 'text/javascript'})));



